# Stuck on word/sentence count

Tags: c#

I'm quite stuck here,don't know how make the count appear like:

> "In the 1 sentence there is 5 words.In the 2 sent.."

and so on.I just get the numbers.
Here is what i have right now:

```
    string sentences=Console.ReadLine();
    foreach (var sentence in sentences.TrimEnd('.').Split('.'))
            Console.WriteLine(sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: So what does this code do atm that isn't right? Please describe what the exact problem is and what you have done so far to try to solve it

Comment: So you just need a counter for the sentences? `int count = 0` outside the loop and `count++` in the WriteLine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string sentences=Console.ReadLine();
int lineNum = 1;
foreach (var sentence in sentences.TrimEnd('.').Split('.'))
{
    Console.WriteLine(lineNum.ToString() + " sentence " + sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count());
    lineNum++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of count, you could use x.Select((o,i) => Tuples.Create(o, i)) to create the index, then write out String.Format("In sentence {0} there are {1} words.", tup.Item2, *your count from tup.Item1*)

This overload of a.Select gives both the number and the index in the sequence.